# how to handle mixed domain (onprem and oncloud users)

Tags: adfs, single-sign-on, office365

i need to setup adfs to activate sso for an application. 
We need to use adfs because we have more tenands and subdomains. But my problem is, that we have some users existing only in cloud but not onpremise, so they will not logon anymore on portal.office.com.
How can i handle that only onprem users logon over ADFS and oncloud users on login.microsoftonline.com. The problem is that all users have the same @domain.com
Is it possible with groupmember ship or do i need to change domainname for the oncloud users?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your exact situation but in general, only users provisioned in Azure AD via AAD Connect will authenticate with ADFS. (@domain)

Users created directly in the cloud in AAD will continue to login into AAD in the cloud. (@microsoftonline)